# What does backslash do in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, string-interpolation

In the following line of code, what is the backslash telling Swift to do?

```
print("The total cost of my meal is \(dictionary["pizza"]! + dictionary["ice cream"]!)")
```

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html Check out printing constants and variables section.

Comment: You should pick the first answer that completely answers your question and accept it.

Comment: Hello, Duncan C, I'm sorry, it was my first question, and I didn't really know how to pick an answer, I found out how to do it, and I did it. Thanks for the comment, I will certainly remember it next time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash has a few different meanings in Swift, depending on the context. In your case, it means string interpolation:

```
print("The total cost of my meal is \(dictionary["pizza"]! + dictionary["ice cream"]!)")
```

...is the same as:

```
print("The total cost of my meal is " + String(dictionary["pizza"]! + dictionary["ice cream"]!))
```

But the first form is more readable. Another example:

```
print("Hello \(person.firstName). You are \(person.age) years old")
```

Which may print something like `Hello John. You are 42 years old`. Much clearer than:

```
print("Hello " + person.firstName + ". You are " + String(person.age) + " years old")
```

Comment: Man, thanks a lot for your time. I really appreciate your explanation. I understand tha better.

Answer (score 3):

That's called String interpolation. When you want to embed the **value** of a variable in a String, you have to put the variable name between parentheses and escape the opening parentheses with a backslash. This way the compiler knows that it has to substitute the value of the variable there instead of using the String literal of the variable name.

For more information on the topic, have a look at the [String interpolation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/StringsAndCharacters.html#ID292) part of the Swift Language Guide.

Comment: Good answer, except that the expression is inside parentheses, (`(` and `)`), not brackets (`[` and `]`).

Comment: I really appreciate our help, David. Thank you for your time. Duncan, thanks for helping me too, mate. I will check the link as soon as I get off work.